# How to build dynamic (shared) libraries of crashpad?

Tags: crash, chromium, ninja, gn, depottools

Crashpad is an error reporting system for c++ apps.
https://chromium.googlesource.com/crashpad/crashpad/+/HEAD/doc/developing.md

build instructions are

```
 $ cd ~/crashpad/crashpad
 $ gn gen out/Default
 $ ninja -C out/Default
```

I can build predefined static libs but I have not found a way how to use `gn` or `ninja` to generate the shared libraries.

Comment: Hello, I'm struggling with the same problem. Have you found a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after you generate ninja files, for each ninja file find the switch /MTd (debug) or /MT (release version) and change it to /MDd or /MD so the dynamic libs will be created

then you can build crashpad with ninja, the output is still lib files so they will be included in the exe file when you link them to your project (you do not have to add them to your project as using dlls).

Answer (score 2):

After running `gn gen out\Default`, you can edit the `out\Default\toolchain.ninja` file to add extra compiler flags to the command for the `cc` and `cxx` rules.

```
rule cc
  command = ninja -t msvc -e environment.amd64 -- cl.exe ... ${cflags} ${cflags_c} /c ...
                                 add the /MD compiler flag after the others, here ^
```

Answer (score 2):

@bobbyg603's answer is *almost* what I needed.

But as usual things are not written by hand but embedded in a script, so opening up an editor to change things is oftentimes not really useful at all. Programmatically, you can also use:

```
gn gen out\Default --args="extra_cflags=\"/MD\""
```

This will also change the arguments for cxx by the way.

Answer (score 1):

We took another look at this today. If you run `gn args --list out\Default` you'll notice the following:

```
extra_cflags
    Current value (from the default) = ""
      From //third_party/mini_chromium/mini_chromium/build/BUILD.gn:50

    Extra flags passed to the C compiler.
    Space-separated string of flags.
    "cflags" are passed to all invocations of the C, C++, Objective-C, and
    Objective-C++ compilers.
```

To add the `/MDd` flag to your build config run `gn args out\Default` and add `extra_cflags="/MDd"` to the build config.