# How do I build Google Crashpad into Shared (Dynamic) Libraries?

Tags: ninja, google-breakpad, gn

**Problem Summary**

I'm trying to integrate [Google Crashpad](https://chromium.googlesource.com/crashpad/crashpad/), (successor of Google Breakpad) a crash reporting system, into a software suite that links to all of its external libraries dynamically. My problem is that the default of Crashpad is to build as a static library - I need to build it *dynamically*.

After cloning Crashpad, [GN](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/tools/gn/+/48062805e19b4697c5fbd926dc649c78b6aaa138/README.md) is used to generate the [.ninja](https://ninja-build.org/) files for the build. The build commands are as follows:

`$ gn gen out/Default`

The above command generates all of the .ninja files.

(Aside) To generate Visual Studio solution files (.sln), the following generation command can be used instead:

`$ gn gen out/Default --ide=vs`

To compile:

`$ ninja -C out/Default`

**What I've Tried**

1. [This StackOverflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55302553/how-to-build-dynamic-shared-libraries-of-crashpad) answers the same question, suggesting that you can simply modify the outputted .ninja files' link flags (/MT changed to /MD). However, grepping over all of the outputted files shows that no such flags exist.
2. [Backtrace Integration Guide](https://help.backtrace.io/en/articles/2337714-crashpad-integration-guide) has a link to pre-built dynamically (shared) libraries of crashpad [here](http://get.backtrace.io/crashpad/builds/). However, they appear to have built those libraries with Visual Studio 2017, using a newer toolset (v141) than I can use. I need to re-build Crashpad for dynamic linking, and using Visual Studio 2015 (v140).

Answer (score 1):

The output of:

`$ gn gen out/Default`

will create a file called **toolchain.ninja**, which contains lines that tell your specified compiler how to compile your projects. In the case of Crashpad, they look like this:

`rule cc
  command = ninja -t msvc -e environment.amd64 -- cl.exe /nologo /showIncludes ${defines} ${include_dirs} ${cflags} ${cflags_c} /c ${in} /Fo${out} /Fd"${target_out_dir}/${label_name}_c.pdb"
  description = CC ${out}
  deps = msvc`

`rule cxx
  command = ninja -t msvc -e environment.amd64 -- cl.exe /nologo /showIncludes ${defines} ${include_dirs} ${cflags} ${cflags_c} /c ${in} /Fo${out} /Fd"${target_out_dir}/${label_name}_cc.pdb"
  description = CXX ${out}
  deps = msvc`

For the Visual Studio MSVC 2015 / 2017 compiler, you can add the `/MD` flag to each `command` line above. This will compile the library dynamically. For example:

`command = ninja -t msvc -e environment.amd64 -- cl.exe /MD /nologo /showIncludes ${defines} ${include_dirs} ${cflags} ${cflags_c} /c ${in} /Fo${out} /Fd"${target_out_dir}/${label_name}_cc.pdb"`